# How To List Types in Assembly or Namespace that have been created at run-time using MakeGenericType?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Consider the following two types:

```
public abstract class Abase {
}

public class MyGeneric<T> : Abase {
}
```

If I create a Type at runtime using MakeGenericType:
How can I query the assembly or namespace later for that type?

```
var paramType = typeof (string);
var myMiscType = typeof (MyGeneric<>).MakeGenericType(paramType);

var assembly = myMiscType.Assembly;
//my type is not in here:
var allTypesfromMyTypeAssembly = (
        from t in assembly.GetTypes()where typeof (Abase).IsAssignableFrom(t)select t);
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uJtTvk)

I tried a few things, but none seem to work.  Is what I want Possible?

Comment: I think `assembly.GetTypes()` does not show run time configured types.

Answer (score 1):

While the assembly for the open generic type and the closed generic type that you created is the same assembly, the closed type is not in the list returned from `Assembly.GetTypes()` as this list represents what was known at compile time.

The best you could do would be to store types you create in another list and concatenate it with `Assembly.GetTypes()`

Comment: Interesting, though in my use case the users have some control over a "schema" so I would need to build some sort of registry of all created types. Hoping there was some builtin method I did not know about to query the AppDomain for types that exist at any given time.